# What is the meaning of 成器 and how do you use it？

Tags: translation, meaning

this new vocab in my textbook says it means: to make something of one's self.

我感觉绝望，我就想成器.

I feel so hopeless, I just want to make something of my self.
is this the right interpretation?

Thanks

Comment: bkrs:成器(1) [utensil]∶做成器具
(2) **[become a useful person]∶比喻成为有用的人
不成器**
(3) [exquisite ware]∶精美的器具, 比喻有才能的人
总角为成器

Comment: I feel that *I just want to make something of my self* is also a correct interpretation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a fixed saying, in modern times, it is usually used in **negative** expressing. i.e. 不成器

我感觉绝望，我就想成器.

People don't use 器 to refer himself, because the criterion is too low, imply that you are not even an ordinary human.

If you really want to use it, use it like this:

1. 他不成器.
2. 一个不成器的家伙.
3. 老话说: 玉不琢不成器, 我要修理修理你.

There is another famous quote from Confucius: 君子不器 which has a totally different meaning, and the view point is not appropriate in modern times.

Answer (score 1):

[器](http://www.zdic.net/z/17/xs/5668.htm) might mean 人才 [talent] or 才能 [capacity;ability]; [成器](http://www.zdic.net/c/0/13e/308319.htm) means *grow up to be a useful person* here.

> [become a useful person]∶比喻成为有用的人

Here're some other usages.

> - 不成器
>     [neer-do-well;good-for-nothing] 谓不能成为有用的器物。后用以比喻不成材,没出息
> - 玉不琢，不成器
>     玉石不经雕琢，成不了器物。比喻人不受教育、不学习就不能有成就。
> - 积厚成器
>     指根基深厚，养成才干。

Comment: users note that 比喻成为有用的人 has been in comment #1, 7 min before being edited into above answer, the source could be 现代汉语词典, it already is in the 1998 edition which in fact only says (does not have (1),(3) of comment #1): 比喻成为有用的人:孩子～是父母的最大安慰

Comment: @user6065 Why are you so concerned with comments posted before answers that you seem to comment under each of these answers? Although it is an etiquette to [notify](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/54718/352986) [commentators](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/82099/352986) to convert comments to answers, comments are not intended to be used as answers, and it's not like other users [can't reference the same sources as the one you're using](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/117268/352986).

Answer (score 1):

成器 comes from the Chinese idioms 玉不琢不成器. Used to describe people without training can not become a useful person.
成器 means be a useful person.

Answer (score 1):

You can just take those explanations from other answers as they're all correct. 
 And as far as I am concerned, we use “出息” in our sentence in place of “成器” in our daily lives.

Answer (score 0):

iciba has:

《圣经》里说:‘孩子不打不成器. ’
Spare the rod and spoil the child, as the Good Book says.

Without the context of the text where you found this sentence, that indicates to me:

我感觉绝望，我就想成器.
I'm so down, I just want to be a useful person.